# MySQL PHP select rows count in date range

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL table for product orderings named TABLE1.

Date means the date purchase has been made

The table has other columns that currently have no influence.

```
PRODUCT_ID | DATE      | other columns
    3      |2018-02-01 | other values
    3      |2018-02-03 | other values
    3      |2018-02-07 | other values
    3      |2018-02-07 | other values
    3      |2018-03-02 | other values
```

I know that the first time the product 3 has been ordered, is 2018-02-01

```
SELECT DATE FROM TABLE1 WHERE PRODUCT_ID = '3' ORDER BY DATE ASC LIMIT 1
```

How do I select count of product orderings per day *within range* of 2018-02-01 and 2019-03-16 (today) so that I could get a table like that:

```
DATE       | ORDERS_PER_DAY
2018-02-01 | 1
2018-02-02 | 0
2018-02-03 | 1
...
2018-02-07 | 2
...
2018-03-02 | 1
...
2018-03-15 | 0
2018-03-16 | 0
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use [GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-modifiers.html) clause to do it.

```
SELECT `DATE`, COUNT(`PRODUCT_ID`) AS ORDERS_PER_DAY
FROM TABLE1
WHERE `DATE` BETWEEN '2018-02-01' AND CURDATE() 
GROUP BY `DATE`
```

This query will result in filtering the records on your required date range and then grouping it by each day where there is data.

Comment: Thanks for this. How could I get the response that in day x there will be 0 product sold?

DATE | ORDERS_PER_DAY
2018-02-04 | 0

Comment: You can write a loop in code PHP code and check `ORDERS_PER_DAY  == 0` to find dates where orders count is 0.

Comment: @userxöa I have modified the query. Please use that.

Answer (score 1):

My syntax may not be exactly correct, but could you try something like this using the `GROUP BY` clause.

```
SELECT DATE, COUNT(*) AS ORDERS_PER_DAY
FROM TABLE1
GROUP BY DATE, PRODUCT_ID
HAVING PRODUCT_ID = '3'
```

you can read more about this here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: Why not `WHERE product_id = 3`?